# Is there a way to execute this code using a For Loop, just curious?

Tags: javascript

This code removes the space between names and inserts a comma. I am curious to know if there is a way to execute the same code using a For Loop in replace of "Split". I remember doing something similar but not enough to actually do it.

```js
function cutName (name) {
    return name.split(' ');
}

alert(cutName("Amjad Ali"));
```

Comment: The code doesn't really insert a comma, that just happens implicitly when the array is converted to a string inside `alert`. You might want to use `.join()` or even `.join(',')` explicitly.

Comment: this relies heavily on `toString` method of `Array`.

Comment: No. There's no good reason to use a loop here. Of course you can reinvent the wheel, er, all string methods, but why would you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the comments that what you are asking seems a bit weird, but here you go:

```js
function cutName(name) {
  let result = "";
  for (let i = 0; i < name.length; i++) {
    if (name[i] === " ") result += ",";
    else result += name[i];
  }
  return result;
}

alert(cutName("Amjad Ali"));
```

This doesn't return an array as `split()` does, but the stringified result is the same (which appears to be what you are after).

---

If you *do* want an array, just like `split()`, try this instead:

```js
function cutName (name) {
    let result = [];
    let lastIndex = 0;
    for(let i=0; i<name.length; i++) {
     if(name[i] === " ") {
       result.push(name.substring(lastIndex, i));
        lastIndex = i+1;
      }
    }
    result.push(name.substring(lastIndex, name.length))
    return result;
}


console.log(cutName("Amjad Ali"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am new to JS, can you explain why “let” us used in lieu of “var”?

Comment: @user8468882, tons of answers out there and you'd be better off just googling that. But basically it prevents you from declaring the same variable twice (which may prevent errors). I can't think of any scenario where using var is preferred over let.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function cutName(name){
  var result = "";
  for(const char of name) result += char === " " ? "," : char;
  return result;
}

console.log(cutName("Jonas W"));
```

You may use a for loop to iterate over every character.